# closing MFC application only using [X] button in title bar and disabling esc shortcut

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog, terminate

I have a dialog based MFC application which I want to close/terminate only using the <kbd>X</kbd>(close) button given in title bar and disabling other shortcuts to do so.
 for example: pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Can someone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828258/how-to-prevent-mfc-dialog-closing-on-enter-and-escape-keys

Answer (score 0):

Override the PreTranslateMessage function and catch the use of VK_ESCAPE for capturing Esc key. Similar way you can catch other messages and bypass closing of dialog

```
BOOL CMyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if ((pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN) || (pMsg->wParam == VK_ESCAPE))
            return TRUE;
    }
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: Copying a [poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17829314/1889329), without attribution, is called *"plagiarism"*. -1 for not even considering the proper MFC way of doing this.

Comment: Please let me know what I am doing here non MFC way, As I have used this in my previous project and copied the same. Let me know what is non MFC way, so that I can make that proper in my project too. Very thanks for your coming answer.